# Learn weather forecast

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

Is there any website for videos/articles that explains how to read maps or other graphics use to make forecast prediction (more advanced than the weather channel please) ?
It could be about any country/region.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What have you tried already?

Comment: @aretxabaleta  Nothing, no idea where to start. I would just like to read post (daily or weekly) about current weather and forecast maps. I  want to work as a forecaster but in my major we only study math and theory of atmospheric sciences,  nothing that helps use read maps on a high level.

Comment: Interested what major/location you are studying in!  Surprised there is nothing in synoptic or mesoscale meteorology at all?  Often they are late courses within the major.

Comment: Atmospheric science in Montreal, Canada. Maybe they come in U3, I would like to start learning them before that

Comment: @katarado - maybe start here - http://www.accuweather.com/en/weather-blogs/anderson ?